# How to modify the color value of ParticlesJS Config. at 'input' event of <input type="color">

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I am using [ParticlesJs](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) for the background of a website project I am working on right now. I want to let the users customize their background with some <input type="color"> but also whenever the value changes, I would like to also change the particles' color value. I managed to make the color change but when I am trying to real-time update it, I always mess something up.

I tried redoing the config with a function **>>** `colorInput.addEventListener("input",()=>{ /*code*/ })` but I am not sure what code to use. I didn't really understand how the particlesJs works when it comes to input other than the main config, so I tried to modify some properties with the method above which as expected just recreates the particles with other settings and lags the page very much. On the [ParticlesJs](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) page, there are many options for real-time customization. What I want is exactly that type of color modifier setting for the real-time update.

I would really appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code here, pls.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov There isn't very much code to show, as I said, I have 3 inputs of type color 

<input runat="server" id="bgCol" type="color" />
and also the event listeners 

bgC.addEventListener('input', () => {
    document.getElementById('particles-js').style.backgroundColor = bgC.value;
    document.cookie = 'bgCol=' + bgC.value;
});

I use cookies to save the values and also this is the event listener for the background, which I can update in real-time, but the color of the particles isn't as easy... or at least doesn't seem that easy for me because I can't refference them in js.